# How to send complex nested JSON from Angular Typescript to Web Api?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

`I have 2 issues with my json data as I am use to sending it "flat"`

**Example typescript class model**

```
UserID: number;
AppID: number;
Key: string;
HearingsAndEventsType: number
```

In the past I would send above like this.

```
{
   "UserID": 61525,
   "AppID": 15,
   "Key": "abc",
   "HearingsAndEventsType": 1
}
```

NOT ANYMORE,  I have to send as the nested object with 2 changes to the JSON object

1. "PageQueryString": {...
2. },
     "HearingsAndEventsType": 1

**THUS the mandatory structure that I need to send will look INSTEAD like this**

```
{
  "PageQueryString": {
      "UserID": 61525,
      "AppID": 15,
      "Key": "abc"
},
    "HearingsAndEventsType": 1
}
```

I tried to ask the question in the link below, but I THINK it was too long in length for people to understand what I was needing.    Thus other question is pretty much the same thing.... so to the person kind and smart enough to help, 2 questions for the price of 1  . thx

[Angular Typescript sending complex json data to web api when model is flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570885/angular-typescript-sending-complex-json-data-to-web-api-when-model-is-flat?noredirect=1#comment84138911_48570885)

Essential i use JSON stringify and try and send model over, but I need to other the json

```
 getPageCommonData(menu: Menu)  {
    return this.http.post(pageCommonData, JSON.stringify(menu), httpOptions)
  ....
 }
```

Comment: ... you can send "complex" objects the same way you send "flat" ones. If that doesn't work for you, you should at the very least describe your attempt and what happened when you tried it.

Comment: ... and please don't repost, if you phrased your question badly, you should edit it instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to create two models:

```
class QueryString {
    UserID: number;
    AppID: number;
    Key: string;
}

class Menu {
    PageQueryString: QueryString;
    HearingsAndEventsType: number;
}
```

Comment: Ok, cool,  so can you help me understand this?   so would i then do   `http.post(pageCommonData, JSON.stringify(OtherModel), httpOptions`  ?

Comment: Above would be based upon if  getPageCommonData(othermodel: OtherModel    and then    JSON.stringify(othermodel)  ...

Comment: Yes. Once you have the values filled in as necessary, this model should produce the json you require. I just called it OtherModel because I didn't see your edit. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Hey, so the link to my other question describes all the component and service data,   there is a guy who simply suggest "what is wrong with json.parse"    i gather that he doesn't get it as how the heck would Web Api magically know to consume the complex structure?